# Where does audio output go in Emacs shell?

Tags: emacs

I open a shell in Emacs via M-x shell.

Then, the line echo -ne '\007' produces no output. However, when I run it in terminal via M-x term, it produces a sound. Is there a way to get shell to have the same behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Set `visible-bell` to `nil` to keep an audible bell. Also make sure `ring-bell-function` is unset and modes such as `echo-bell-mode` are not loaded.

You can start with:

```
(setq visible-bell nil)
```

See if that solves it.

Otherwise, this page might come helpful:
https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AlarmBell